# How to let react only render part of the component?

Tags: reactjs, grid

I am writing a react app with css grids. I'm not going to include the css here but it is a 2x2 grid.

```
import { useState } from 'react';

function Container() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className = "gridwrapper">
        <div className = "top_left"> <SomeCustomComponent></div>
        <div className = "bottom_left"> <CustomCounter counter = {count}></div>
        <div className = "bottom_right"> <CustomCounter counter = {count+2}></div>
        <div className = "top_right"><button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Click me</button><div>
    </div>
  );
}

function CustomCounter({count}){
return(<p>The count is {count}</p>)
}
```

I have two issues right now

1. Since setState would cause re-render, now it would re-render the whole thing. But I only need the bottom two cells to re-render since other parts of my Container component do not even depend on props.
2. In order for my grid structure to work properly, I need to wrap them in divs, why is that? I tried to assign classnames directly before but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding unnecessary re-renders - don't worry about it. The React diffing engine is smart enough to know which elements have actually changed and which ones haven't, and it will only update what is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could use a useEffect listener to only change when specific variables change. As far as I know you can not just re-render a part of the component.
2. When you make a custom component, you need to make the className prop available on the child component aswell.

e.g.

```
function SomeCustomComponent(props) {
  return (
    <div className={props.className}>
       // ... your component stuff here ..
    </div>
  )
}
```